# Recargar funciones despues de respuesta de ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cuando escribo un comentario en mi página, genero un ajax para guardar el comentario en la base de datos, y la respuesta es el comentario en html, este mismo comentario tiene unas etiquetas parecidas a la siquiente.

```
<a href="#" action="delete">Borrar</a>
```

La función de action la tengo en el archivo .js

```
$('a[action]').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     // Resto de la función...
});
```

El problema es que al introducir el código en el documento html esa función no funciona, valga la redundancia.

Introduzco el código con un .append() en el success:function() de ajax

```
$.ajax({..., success:function(e){
     $('#div').append(e.codigo);}});
```

Como hago para no tener que volver a recargar todo el archivo .js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, no me queda del todo claro la funcionalidad. Sin embargo, si lo que quieres es que el link con "action=delete" funcione, luego de cargarlo dinamicamente con ajax, debes hacer uso de la delegacion de eventos que te ofrece jquery (con el metodo on).

En todo caso, si es eso, en tú código JS, tendrias que colocar algo asi:

```
$("#contenedor-comentarios").on('click','a[action="delete"]',tuFuncion)
```

Esto suponiendo que #contenedor-comentarios es el ID del div padre en donde agregas los comentarios. Tiene que ser un div que no sea reemplazado y exista desde el momento en que cargas la página, de esta forma jquery podrá identificar si existen cambios dentro de el (cuando agregas un comentario con su respectiva accion para borrar) y podrá activar la función sobre el enlace con "action=delete".
Pd: De repente sea mejor, que en el action, agregues un link real y manejes la funcionalidad con un campo data.

Espero te sirva, 
saludos.

Comment: Grácias por la ayuda, funciona perfecto.

Comment: a tu orden. calificala. Saludos